# Errores al instalar la libreria chatterbot de python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pip

Estoy intentando instalar chatterbot en python en windows 11, pero cuando se esta instalando con pip, me sale el siguiente mensaje:

```
maps.cpp
        c1xx: fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo origen: 'preshed/maps.cpp': No such file or directory
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure

      Encountered error while trying to install package.

      preshed

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

No se como solucionar este error, pero no me deja instalar chatterbot, no tengo instalado Visual Studio Community 2019, solamente tengo instalado Visual Studio Build Tools 2019, ya que pip me recomendo que lo instalara para que se pueda instalar chatterbot, pero al final resulto que ocurrio otro error que es el que puse aqui.

Comment: Bienvenido Dylan, siempre que puedas pega texto en lugar de capturas de pantalla de errores. Mejor para todos, saludos!

Comment: Buenas tardes, okey gracias, ya lo puse en texto

Answer (score 0):

hola tuve el error un par de dias si estas en w11 y tienes la versión de python 10 instalate la una versión nueva te dejo la que me instale yo

pip install ChatterBot2

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/344262)